# Can not declare or use a variable when it is defined in anther file

Tags: typescript

I have two files in one folder.

```sh
# ls
a.ts  
b.ts
tsconfig.json

# tsc --version 
Version 3.0.1
```

And `tsconfig.json` is created by `tsc -init` without any change.

In `a.ts`, I define a variable.

```
let a = {
  name: 'hello'
}
```

In `b.ts`:

```
let a = {}
```

And I try to compiler:

```
# tsc
a.ts:1:5 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'a'.
// ... and some detail
```

So compiler throw this error, but it also gives me two compiled files.

```
# ls
a.js         
b.ts
a.ts         
tsconfig.json
b.js
```

This is detail in `b.js`:

```
"use strict";
var a = {};
```

Actual, compile is successful, but it still throws an error.

[image]

### anther test

But if I try to use `a` in `b.ts`

```
console.log(a.name)
```

Compiler is fine, but failed when I try to execute the code.

So, I am confused. I can not declare or use `a` as a variable name in `b.ts` when I define this in anther file?

This is default `tsconf.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you loading these files? Are they scripts or modules? It sounds like `b.ts` has another `a` in it that *isn't* the `a` in `a.ts`.

Comment: did you have ```"strict": true```, in ```tsconfig.json```

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien - I'm curious why that would matter? The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) doesn't immediately suggest how `strict` would relate to the above.

Comment: if it is not stricted, the variable could be shared between .ts files, as they're not local variable anymore. So I assumed it is the issue

Comment: and when you use console.log(a.name), you have to be sure a is created. That mean a.ts must be before b.ts, which could be wrong

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien - I don't see anything in the documentation about `strict` changing variable scope. Can you point me at it?

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien strict ha nothing to do with that, files with no exports are considered script fiels under strict too

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok

Comment: This seems a bit like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do with `a`? And how are you running these files?

Answer (score 1):

If your file contains no exports it is considered a script file, and all symbols declared inside it are in the global scope. This is probably why you are getting the error, you are defining the same variable in multiple files typescript considers script files.

You can either use `namespaces` (not recommended) or you could add a module system and use `export` al least once in your file.

If you are already using a module system, and just forgot to add an `export` you can add the `isolatedModules` to ensure all files are required to have at least one export

Comment: But in that case, why would trying to use `a` (without redeclaring it) not work? If the first is considered a script and the `a` becomes global...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe the file is not loaded in the environment for other reasons ? The ts part of the error strongly suggests the files are not treated as modules. Maybe OP can offer more info on the environment, to have a better understating of why it  fails at runtime, but I am pretty confident of the TS part of it.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but failed when I try to execute the code.

That tells us that you're not running `a.js` before running `b.js` in the same environment. You can't just run `b.js` in isolation, `a.js` has to be run first so that `a` is declared and initialized.

If you do that, `console.log(a.name)` in `b.js` works just fine.

Using TypeScript v3 with your `tsconfig.json`, `a.ts` is compiled to this JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
var a = {
    name: 'hello'
};
```

and `b.ts` (the version with the `console.log`) is compiled to this JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
console.log(a.name);
```

Running `a.js` and then running `b.js` in the same environment successfully outputs the name. [Live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6utF5OzBNBSMFpiXubZ1?p=preview)

The reason you can't redeclare `a` in `b.ts` is that both `a.ts` and `b.ts` are evaluated at global scope, and you can't have `let a` at global scope in two places, because redeclaring variables with `let` is an error.